# add react-beautiful-dnd has warnings; doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm working through the author's tutorial, `task-app` on https://egghead.io/courses/beautiful-and-accessible-drag-and-drop-with-react-beautiful-dnd. My code is identical, but the app does not work. Could it be because of the warnings? This is my first attempt to use react outside of codeSandbox. I started with `>npx create-react-app task-app`, `imported styled-components`, which worked, and then typed `>yarn add react-beautiful-dnd`. Among others, the following warnings appeared:

> warning " > react-beautiful-dnd@13.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency
> "react@^16.8.5".
>
> warning " > react-beautiful-dnd@13.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency
> "react-dom@^16.8.5".

Finally, drag and drop did not work even though my code was identical to the code in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ref` for **HTML DOM** element and use `innerRef` for **React** component
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/using-inner-ref.md#a-common-error-

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out. The tutorial and the sample code that goes with it has a line that's old. innerRef argument should be ref. I would show an example but I can't format the code so that I can post.